# When are PIMS and Irreducibles not in correspondence?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $A$ be an algebra over some field $k$. Let $K_P(A)$ be the Grothendieck group of the category of projective $A$-modules and $K_F(A)$ the category of finite dimensional $A$-modules. I've been told there are examples where $K_P(A)$ and $K_F(A)$ have different rank, but I've never seen an example.

Does anyone have such an example?

Comment: What does PIMS stand for?

Comment: projective indecomposable modules

Comment: I guess the first use of PIM was as an abbreviation for "principal indecomposable module", before the notion of projective module became widespread in this kind of algebra.   Fortunately "principal" and "projective" both start with the same letter, though it's actually a little more natural to write "indecomposable projective module".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A=k[x]$. Then $K_P(A)$ has rank 1 (I assume that you consider only finitely generated projective modules) and $K_F(A)$ has infinite rank.

Comment: Do you know one where both are finite dimensional?


Answer (score 3):

If k is an algebraically closed field, then A = { f(x)/g(x) : g(0)⋅g(1) ≠ 0; f,g in k[x] } ≤ k(x) is a commutative ring with exactly two maximal ideals, (x) and (x−1).  It has two simple modules and both happen to be one dimensional as k-vector spaces.  It is a PID, so it has only one projective indecomposable module, which is of course free and cyclic as an A-module, but infinite dimensional as a k-vector space.

Hence the rank of K<sub>P</sub>(A) is 1, and the rank of K<sub>F</sub>(A) is 2.

This is just a modification of Victor Ostrik's example to cut down on the number of simple modules.

Answer (score 2):

An example where both groups are of finite rank but different is the Weyl algebra. There are no finite dimensional modules, so one of the groups is trivial, and $K_0(A)=\mathbb Z$.

(I'm considering the $K_0$ if *f.g.* projectives...)

Comment: Is there anything in between? In some sense, this is the same example with the reciprocal of the rank.

Comment: «this is the same example with the reciprocal of the rank»? I don't 
know what you mean by that.

Comment: In Victor's example, there were infinitely many simples but one projective. In your example, there is 1 projective and no simples. The algebras are related by x↔\partial/\partial x so it's like you're taking reciprocals

Comment: The Weyl algebra is generated by $x$ *and* $d/dx$. Also, it has many, many simple modules, but all of them infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Also, there are many non-isomorphic projectives, but they collapse in $K_0$.

Comment: Agreed. Do you have an example where both ranks are finite and nonzero?


Comment: Well... $k\times A$ with $k$ a field and $A$ the Weyl algebra over $k$ :)